# Standardizing data to 100 as mean

Tags: r

So I have a data frame column with the quantiles looking like

```
  0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
-4.268446 -3.845898 -3.703559 -3.471152 -1.423046
```

And the mean being

```
[1] -3.624417
```

And the Stdev being

```
[1] 0.317673
```

I want to standardize this number, with the mean being 100, and the best value (the max) being some above 100. And any value should be 100-x% better/worse than the mean.

So if the value is 110, it should be 10% greater than the mean, if it is 90, it should be 10% lower than the mean.

I've tried the way I usually do to standardize this way by doing

value / mean * 100

But that makes the worse values valued higher.

Data:

```
-3.97538471221924, -4.03633117675781, -3.87677073478699, -4.02991914749146, 
-3.79488945007324, -3.91195774078369, -3.40139174461365, -3.9614691734314, 
-3.93642282485962, -3.96477675437927, -4.01250791549683, -3.8091995716095, 
-3.80822944641113, -3.93599319458008, -4.02784824371338, -3.88542246818542, 
-3.91709470748901, -3.98224830627441, -3.94417905807495, -3.86284017562866, 
-3.41096329689026, -3.7353835105896, -3.71642065048218, -3.55353283882141, 
-4.02844429016113, -3.85334920883179, -4.06265878677368, -3.79221558570862, 
-3.90409469604492, -3.88372683525085, -3.95370626449585, -3.72801995277405, 
-3.82603287696838, -3.83546590805054, -3.89339137077332, -4.02618312835693, 
-4.13694334030151, -4.00073385238647, -3.70431160926819, -3.70322775840759, 
-3.6907684803009, -3.6743323802948, -3.55570387840271, -3.74284887313843, 
-3.81651067733765, -3.79823303222656, -3.63184642791748, -3.69253540039062, 
-3.90661644935608, -3.68085050582886, -3.74880218505859, -3.78952670097351, 
-3.97141551971436, -3.65802931785583, -3.75592255592346, -3.71408581733704, 
-3.85596609115601, -3.94590282440186, -3.71768808364868, -3.76207995414734, 
-3.96590733528137, -3.72186064720154, -3.86649322509766, -4.11467838287354, 
-3.57397794723511, -3.9344654083252, -3.98242616653442, -3.78900980949402, 
-3.63569903373718, -3.81575536727905, -3.87250208854675, -3.67492651939392, 
-3.51991653442383, -3.89527249336243, -3.71350407600403, -3.56796193122864, 
-3.92774391174316, -3.60959529876709, -3.88178491592407, -3.48982381820679, 
-3.4348566532135, -3.5809531211853, -3.17587733268738, -3.87362003326416, 
-3.79246163368225, -3.79063200950623, -2.91180682182312, -3.71088171005249, 
-3.78244543075562, -3.98379302024841, -3.90634751319885, -3.94800710678101, 
-3.90845799446106, -3.96009588241577, -3.92725515365601, -3.57416152954102, 
-3.8913094997406, -3.86767315864563, -3.85355615615845, -3.80331969261169, 
-3.72159790992737, -3.74618768692017, -3.83934307098389, -3.91287302970886, 
-3.36160373687744, -3.7010862827301, -3.7587628364563, -3.71295642852783, 
-3.67227625846863, -3.73000693321228, -3.46050667762756, -3.62400007247925, 
-3.80334258079529, -3.83266353607178, -3.69702124595642, -3.94881415367126, 
-3.9519317150116, -3.47320866584778, -3.64875388145447, -3.77908182144165, 
-3.63412666320801, -3.1906476020813, -3.76621127128601, -3.68045282363892, 
-3.72943425178528, -3.72829508781433, -3.79161429405212, -3.95967578887939, 
-3.79868340492249, -3.38448143005371, -3.31477284431458, -3.76011776924133, 
-3.46951460838318, -3.75917553901672, -3.66875672340393, -3.53925848007202, 
-3.57593822479248, -3.83624768257141, -3.75747799873352, -3.44656205177307, 
-3.74803280830383, -3.59486937522888, -3.48907017707825, -4.02844476699829, 
-3.6827507019043, -3.16953134536743, -3.98020601272583, -3.89849543571472, 
-3.7525749206543, -3.43184947967529, -3.75879907608032, -3.52449154853821, 
-3.83425045013428, -3.64572978019714, -3.81346106529236, -4.00846385955811, 
-3.99303269386292, -3.87788319587708, -3.80298495292664, -3.22209715843201, 
-3.90183568000793, -4.07189750671387, -3.85051155090332, -3.79725503921509, 
-3.60880947113037, -3.93472957611084, -3.87805151939392, -3.82712888717651, 
-3.58094239234924, -3.95107913017273, -3.68951559066772, -3.95746469497681, 
-3.70801568031311, -3.8672251701355, -4.01166439056396, -3.69868183135986, 
-3.19171905517578, -3.77929925918579, -3.82915234565735, -3.78899431228638, 
-3.92233300209045, -3.81641292572021, -4.04679346084595, -3.82832455635071, 
-3.98563838005066, -3.98430967330933, -3.98333024978638, -3.8885395526886, 
-3.78952097892761, -2.87893319129944, -3.85598373413086, -3.70232534408569, 
-3.81125259399414, -3.55977654457092, -3.71324777603149, -3.94458103179932, 
-3.88458561897278, -4.10616493225098, -3.90690994262695, -3.85729098320007, 
-3.91699838638306, -3.64505314826965, -3.58733820915222, -3.89484143257141, 
-3.95110273361206, -3.80585527420044, -3.99349117279053, -3.58788657188416, 
-3.66953229904175, -3.85401892662048, -3.82574796676636, -3.83196234703064, 
-2.8057165145874, -3.90388536453247, -3.97097420692444, -3.99488759040833, 
-3.89014530181885, -3.61962747573853, -3.9969310760498, -3.91556549072266, 
-3.98471879959106, -3.86779880523682, -3.78968119621277, -3.85359716415405, 
-3.99872970581055, -3.97902798652649, -4.0496563911438, -4.044264793396, 
-4.16110563278198, -3.74309611320496, -4.02930116653442, -3.80093669891357, 
-3.69188499450684, -3.88977789878845, -3.4475040435791, -3.65659761428833, 
-3.98045349121094, -3.8085355758667, -3.98344850540161, -3.98390483856201, 
-3.64756560325623, -3.89985251426697, -4.04820775985718, -3.97336506843567, 
-3.56822943687439, -3.95363712310791, -3.74132680892944, -3.70492768287659, 
-3.98133516311646, -4.05388259887695, -4.02209329605103, -3.77282333374023, 
-3.45054912567139, -3.50024080276489, -3.59685659408569, -3.43662738800049, 
-3.63247585296631, -4.10710954666138, -3.62999796867371, -3.66752219200134, 
-3.41205930709839, -3.73539137840271, -3.73629808425903, -3.66872644424438, 
-3.26503872871399, -3.42189145088196, -3.47600364685059, -3.49757504463196, 
-3.64225840568542, -3.46634387969971, -3.55641937255859, -3.45491290092468, 
-3.92225766181946, -3.66502547264099, -3.83520698547363, -3.52494525909424, 
-3.37540125846863, -3.58060193061829, -3.65587115287781, -3.99564862251282, 
-3.73568272590637, -3.35761952400208, -3.91516709327698, -3.62396287918091, 
-3.40927290916443, -3.79662036895752, -4.01787281036377, -3.84978127479553, 
-3.91856098175049, -3.86173415184021, -3.72853899002075, -3.76478505134583, 
-3.36698126792908, -3.48069453239441, -3.55567741394043, -3.85630750656128, 
-3.52923560142517, -3.53935313224792, -3.63071393966675, -3.45006847381592, 
-2.93769598007202, -3.61013865470886, -3.43070220947266, -3.92321372032166, 
-3.76144576072693, -3.79359364509583, -3.87417531013489, -3.9336986541748, 
-3.5157413482666, -3.71064376831055, -2.9714732170105, -3.73063230514526, 
-3.35321664810181, -3.63517212867737, -3.77552223205566, -3.49029731750488, 
-3.17867803573608, -3.54090762138367, -2.45766162872314, -4.02418327331543, 
-3.87001729011536, -4.10077285766602, -3.62546110153198, -3.64222574234009, 
-3.88330054283142, -3.56282114982605, -3.61515426635742, -3.24444961547852, 
-2.82647752761841, -3.06863236427307, -3.81353950500488, -3.33756184577942, 
-3.70959162712097, -3.95612025260925, -3.91558146476746, -3.80406260490417, 
-3.89166712760925, -3.78039765357971, -3.85244989395142, -3.63634634017944, 
-3.42855095863342, -3.21893286705017, -3.36617493629456, -3.57498550415039, 
-3.86023592948914, -3.69558119773865, -3.63020443916321, -3.60874652862549, 
-3.40745449066162, -3.50279140472412, -3.06296610832214, -3.76933717727661, 
-3.62093591690063, -3.69518232345581, -3.86359024047852, -3.91861510276794, 
-3.92380261421204, -3.90633678436279, -3.6790599822998, -3.7373673915863, 
-3.76262021064758, -3.50792694091797, -3.67407989501953, -3.76928091049194, 
-4.0582423210144, -3.81838488578796, -3.58534836769104, -3.65886163711548, 
-3.78383016586304, -3.90213131904602, -3.69448685646057, -3.71381974220276, 
-3.52509903907776, -3.60156679153442, -3.39334988594055, -3.51356983184814, 
-3.92306041717529, -3.47452521324158, -3.61734461784363, -3.50239539146423, 
-3.37505388259888, -3.18763089179993, -3.49740290641785, -3.66131401062012, 
-3.62829113006592, -3.68468260765076, -3.75209355354309, -3.75271415710449, 
-3.69411373138428, -2.77759480476379, -3.74766898155212, -3.52980995178223, 
-3.59825086593628, -3.65750503540039, -3.93719911575317, -3.79763698577881, 
-3.85013008117676, -4.03105401992798, -3.46061277389526, -3.66456437110901, 
-3.55882811546326, -3.54450440406799, -3.41921782493591, -3.92438840866089, 
-3.72193312644958, -3.86339855194092, -4.03874826431274, -3.69732189178467, 
-3.8351194858551, -3.8015992641449, -3.80161643028259, -3.65208578109741, 
-3.79024457931519, -3.48122930526733, -3.72820734977722, -3.53262591362, 
-3.52883434295654, -3.41115498542786, -3.71951699256897, -3.79528093338013, 
-3.81181025505066, -3.71050381660461, -3.90315413475037, -3.5734715461731, 
-3.78115916252136, -3.57761526107788, -3.72640514373779, -3.66720581054688, 
-3.6304247379303, -3.5702006816864, -3.39984560012817, -3.53519535064697, 
-3.61167192459106, -3.68269014358521, -3.26859545707703, -3.6171395778656, 
-3.60665845870972, -3.76399159431458, -3.77596545219421, -3.92102694511414, 
-3.92575907707214, -3.68911933898926, -4.18510437011719, -3.73320031166077, 
-3.99491763114929, -3.51348233222961, -3.77415204048157, -3.45711183547974, 
-3.50460648536682, -3.4174177646637, -3.46176195144653, -3.85838484764099, 
-3.96192145347595, -3.82975554466248, -3.72961354255676, -3.82260394096375, 
-3.6811637878418, -3.97078728675842, -3.63247632980347, -3.81403136253357, 
-3.70760011672974, -3.92165374755859, -3.5229127407074, -3.7395396232605, 
-3.51517677307129, -3.85003232955933, -3.87745881080627, -3.98515510559082, 
-3.9702582359314, -3.13649296760559, -3.61438632011414, -3.51885533332825, 
-3.74724745750427, -3.87342977523804, -3.84642744064331, -3.75468564033508, 
-3.09723544120789, -3.3376772403717, -3.35698318481445, -3.0506489276886, 
-3.99500441551208, -3.98846793174744, -3.90907526016235, -3.88767337799072, 
-3.96439623832703, -3.7422308921814, -3.93786311149597, -3.8715877532959, 
-4.05784797668457, -3.7482750415802, -3.7568473815918, -3.5832633972168, 
-3.69051432609558, -3.72015786170959, -3.47158145904541, -3.32531762123108, 
-3.67324376106262, -3.35371518135071, -3.08908629417419, -3.25180983543396, 
-3.07946443557739, -3.98993563652039, -3.81793451309204, -3.81835889816284, 
-3.79566335678101, -2.89821481704712, -3.62529897689819, -3.50772905349731, 
-3.94968271255493, -3.87716197967529, -3.96801495552063, -3.98464012145996, 
-3.88391184806824, -3.843416929245, -4.03314065933228, -3.30473852157593, 
-3.5066294670105, -3.78265929222107, -3.54864072799683, -3.88818311691284, 
-3.99744534492493, -3.79671812057495, -3.82406997680664, -3.92254400253296, 
-3.43501138687134, -3.58028507232666, -3.48677062988281, -3.63395857810974, 
-3.85402917861938, -3.649258852005, -3.67377281188965, -3.73145008087158, 
-3.72327852249146, -4.0343222618103, -4.00593709945679, -4.02137851715088, 
-3.864333152771, -3.81399536132812, -3.95983672142029, -3.80574679374695, 
-3.88052701950073, -3.74715924263, -3.74981117248535, -3.75576639175415, 
-3.65413999557495, -3.91316938400269, -3.71495294570923, -3.52485513687134, 
-3.61426591873169, -3.63264894485474, -3.73169493675232, -3.82824110984802, 
-3.5523681640625, -3.67900657653809, -3.33877086639404, -3.74804019927979, 
-3.82265424728394, -3.75421357154846, -3.83115983009338, -4.10310363769531, 
-3.79956531524658, -3.81999707221985, -3.82675552368164, -3.78261804580688, 
-3.92538380622864, -3.52060317993164, -3.89132571220398, -3.69813966751099, 
-3.84863138198853, -3.71613025665283, -3.90273976325989, -4.07198905944824, 
-3.80914616584778, -3.46760892868042, -3.37204074859619, -3.92594861984253, 
-3.71575474739075, -3.82060241699219, -3.88538932800293, -3.57474446296692, 
-3.80261135101318, -4.01138925552368, -3.65717434883118, -3.76246643066406, 
-3.83523797988892, -3.78447580337524, -3.86432671546936, -3.60525727272034, 
-3.75654339790344, -3.69058179855347, -3.63833165168762, -3.74853205680847, 
-3.76146864891052, -3.79107427597046, -3.92640542984009, -3.92025947570801, 
-3.7628276348114, -2.96676921844482, -3.41629362106323, -2.57589411735535, 
-3.52975416183472, -2.80303311347961, -3.73450446128845, -3.34880566596985, 
-3.71425557136536, -3.15406489372253, -2.88018798828125, -3.92011165618896, 
-3.81168675422668, -3.27787494659424, -4.05513095855713, -3.76444482803345, 
-3.81893134117126, -3.59679985046387, -3.76909375190735, -3.63416957855225, 
-3.62479901313782, -3.76969218254089, -3.36104512214661, -3.78254914283752, 
-3.64234781265259, -3.61270141601562, -3.73260068893433, -3.54765295982361, 
-3.77926778793335, -3.9126455783844, -3.74173879623413, -3.54676127433777, 
-3.57240295410156, -3.72134923934937, -3.44884490966797, -3.83935356140137, 
-3.74139857292175, -3.60605764389038, -4.0147180557251, -3.72229814529419, 
-3.69961333274841, -3.65514183044434, -3.80890965461731, -3.569504737854, 
-3.99846625328064, -3.46503067016602, -3.51051664352417, -3.80844783782959, 
-3.84405899047852, -3.83018589019775, -3.98196315765381, -3.68799805641174, 
-4.03016662597656, -3.93821740150452, -3.85036730766296, -4.1278715133667, 
-3.53719091415405, -3.67712831497192, -3.93036437034607, -3.43891334533691, 
-3.78025197982788, -3.71555924415588, -3.79376912117004, -3.95555472373962, 
-3.20343589782715, -3.73260688781738, -4.00126981735229, -3.49562573432922, 
-3.55170726776123, -3.88768339157104, -3.34807634353638, -3.83792567253113, 
-3.92426943778992, -3.85686063766479, -3.81910252571106, -4.01943588256836, 
-3.80265259742737, -3.69367694854736, -3.61498165130615, -3.58772897720337, 
-3.34260320663452, -3.54081583023071, -3.41968464851379, -3.45494699478149, 
-3.85681414604187, -3.99500298500061, -3.64686679840088, -3.81371188163757, 
-3.84536957740784, -3.73042774200439, -3.86597657203674, -3.9724600315094, 
-3.90354657173157, -3.86272406578064, -3.54892206192017, -3.73103260993958, 
-3.62121391296387, -3.60783791542053, -3.710529088974, -3.78796553611755, 
-3.9299840927124, -3.34133744239807, -3.74241399765015, -3.68722558021545, 
-3.38786339759827, -3.76443886756897, -3.63758540153503, -3.51769948005676, 
-3.54523491859436, -3.62473011016846, -3.63334083557129, -3.96113061904907, 
-3.75337147712708, -3.85787677764893, -3.82297611236572, -3.72693467140198, 
-3.88436055183411, -3.61451244354248, -3.61989164352417, -3.72942686080933, 
-4.07498168945312, -3.95521259307861, -3.98006510734558, -3.63672518730164, 
-3.70704627037048, -4.0377836227417, -3.39142179489136, -3.43590688705444, 
-2.44115734100342, -3.93659615516663, -3.97017478942871, -3.85932970046997, 
-3.86329340934753, -3.71943306922913, -3.39061784744263, -3.74052739143372, 
-2.94148635864258, -3.56156611442566, -4.01366758346558, -3.90712881088257, 
-3.47811269760132, -3.22426199913025, -3.45689725875854, -3.46678066253662, 
-3.13964200019836, -3.34564208984375, -3.19758176803589, -3.52023649215698, 
-3.64792680740356, -3.61834406852722, -3.58724355697632, -3.50748181343079, 
-3.65577912330627, -3.78065633773804, -3.82377624511719, -3.87219619750977, 
-3.37105274200439, -3.56080031394958, -3.68060278892517, -3.81070423126221, 
-3.65744924545288, -3.55540490150452, -3.36764478683472, -3.60673117637634, 
-3.92510652542114, -3.23766851425171, -3.78084206581116, -3.8031690120697, 
-3.59173107147217, -3.42312383651733, -3.67490434646606, -3.81039547920227, 
-3.86749577522278, -3.80046653747559, -3.51131772994995, -3.5428569316864, 
-3.7054123878479, -3.76358222961426, -3.63029813766479, -3.65823817253113, 
-3.87188005447388, -3.65591430664062, -3.87001085281372, -3.82757210731506, 
-3.16145372390747, -3.97476768493652, -3.59298753738403, -3.73642778396606, 
-3.79994654655457, -3.89668774604797, -4.01786231994629, -3.99708604812622, 
-3.94176983833313, -3.8647096157074, -3.89766311645508, -3.80278873443604, 
-3.99250793457031, -4.02426767349243, -4.10021066665649, -3.39703774452209, 
-3.26359176635742, -3.82671117782593, -3.81313323974609, -3.43604493141174, 
-3.31377339363098, -3.80798125267029, -3.81451535224915, -4.07718801498413, 
-3.72391510009766, -3.08661699295044, -3.76619458198547, -3.83467435836792, 
-3.84827923774719, -3.88853645324707, -3.79065752029419, -3.82326292991638, 
-3.34796190261841, -4.02198314666748, -3.92778158187866, -3.62070775032043, 
-3.82512187957764, -3.70889115333557, -3.81021595001221, -3.85158038139343, 
-3.79376363754272, -3.875408411026, -3.75661754608154, -3.96288800239563, 
-3.94140219688416, -3.74917697906494, -3.68129587173462, -3.78641748428345, 
-3.52331447601318, -3.36141896247864, -3.88113570213318, -2.99620270729065, 
-3.86633539199829, -3.68766975402832, -3.65976810455322, -3.70610952377319, 
-3.38187885284424, -3.70525312423706, -3.81387853622437, -3.88207864761353, 
-3.60756802558899, -3.75014662742615, -3.33153533935547, -3.18031525611877, 
-3.72099876403809, -3.8076856136322, -3.67741799354553, -3.71635913848877, 
-4.04951238632202, -3.74342226982117, -3.93503856658936, -3.99668455123901, 
-3.83283662796021, -3.96427869796753, -3.91281938552856, -4.01104164123535, 
-4.12361478805542, -3.49834251403809, -3.69158387184143, -3.70991778373718, 
-3.77035188674927, -3.73654866218567, -3.58738207817078, -3.93428349494934, 
-4.09196758270264, -3.68657469749451, -3.55566501617432, -3.50684690475464, 
-3.59922695159912, -3.82266092300415, -3.61335706710815, -3.65858793258667, 
-3.84981679916382, -3.73356938362122, -3.87916350364685, -3.77270436286926, 
-3.89338707923889, -3.67522549629211, -3.80304479598999, -3.92915940284729, 
-3.62608790397644, -3.7146475315094, -3.19878935813904, -3.84145474433899, 
-3.67336130142212, -3.75900483131409, -3.77894949913025, -3.7319495677948, 
-3.97335457801819, -4.0653977394104, -3.94989037513733, -4.03973150253296, 
-3.75971102714539, -3.6455090045929, -3.64915871620178, -3.8141827583313, 
-3.90111184120178, -3.75651788711548, -3.62716436386108, -3.54678297042847, 
-3.75648069381714, -3.89319491386414, -4.01765012741089, -3.68124341964722, 
-3.53644680976868, -3.75795292854309, -3.62451767921448, -3.80958104133606, 
-3.5502712726593, -3.83708763122559, -3.556560754776, -3.69092893600464, 
-2.76485157012939, -3.21907234191895, -3.67799139022827, -3.87315726280212, 
-3.91908407211304, -3.83191752433777, -3.98365211486816, -3.89440631866455, 
-3.76949167251587, -3.77768683433533, -3.83335590362549, -3.8156430721283, 
-3.96391773223877, -3.85391211509705, -3.96095585823059, -3.92816495895386, 
-3.73137664794922, -3.62495374679565, -3.89675331115723, -3.81962633132935, 
-4.00135278701782, -3.75711274147034, -3.45405077934265, -3.47705769538879, 
-3.66829466819763, -3.203857421875, -4.1542181968689, -3.79695463180542, 
-3.67982244491577, -3.97755575180054, -3.70538926124573, -3.73775625228882, 
-3.63174986839294, -3.82852816581726, -3.81266474723816, -3.57111001014709, 
-3.69380807876587, -3.76427030563354, -3.72001457214355, -3.72431659698486, 
-3.75455355644226, -3.61129784584045, -3.74940323829651, -3.80048871040344, 
-3.8577663898468, -3.85973215103149, -3.80843257904053, -3.9712381362915, 
-3.66903376579285, -4.0623836517334, -3.51091074943542, -3.98390460014343, 
-3.96623015403748, -3.90212512016296, -3.80060911178589, -3.84315299987793, 
-3.50798034667969, -3.73342847824097, -3.48506736755371, -3.94630765914917, 
-3.19087338447571, -3.47729897499084, -3.16243934631348, -3.86419224739075, 
-3.76706266403198, -3.94075512886047, -3.97516179084778, -3.74776673316956, 
-3.84644770622253, -3.88299155235291, -3.89002251625061, -3.87353229522705, 
-3.93982410430908, -3.62951350212097, -3.70244455337524, -3.5008864402771, 
-3.59969925880432, -3.68025517463684, -3.23367619514465, -3.44335341453552, 
-3.70403838157654, -3.67157292366028, -3.45795941352844, -3.56970477104187, 
-3.6645519733429, -3.38615775108337, -3.59955024719238, -3.54332137107849, 
-3.55048751831055, -3.59047031402588, -3.48982715606689, -3.71279692649841, 
-3.89534473419189, -3.49593186378479, -3.22738265991211, -3.6751070022583, 
-3.48276782035828, -3.52480053901672, -3.53807759284973, -3.7566659450531, 
-3.59930944442749, -3.43871521949768, -3.28517746925354, -3.55587458610535, 
-3.54328560829163, -3.26904964447021, -3.27183699607849, -3.41104817390442, 
-3.48867750167847, -3.7642650604248, -3.84013152122498, -3.80252146720886, 
-3.83257961273193, -3.95601034164429, -3.80873441696167, -3.94621109962463, 
-3.92282319068909, -3.71384572982788, -3.98516297340393, -3.86579823493958, 
-3.72224903106689, -3.5329053401947, -3.95190286636353, -3.6790075302124, 
-3.03383803367615, -3.88659405708313, -3.74973678588867, -3.41382384300232, 
-3.39654207229614, -2.76125597953796, -4.1404070854187, -3.8703727722168, 
-3.80810523033142, -3.80035138130188, -3.67795181274414, -3.92546987533569, 
-3.82394599914551, -3.84174799919128, -3.7097020149231, -3.62672233581543, 
-3.69019556045532, -3.4281063079834, -3.23178672790527, -3.37821459770203, 
-3.90212202072144, -4.04663467407227, -3.65541696548462, -4.01369285583496, 
-3.61924171447754, -3.91963672637939, -3.82316422462463, -3.82684969902039, 
-3.44636225700378, -3.43918633460999, -3.46366119384766, -3.66606950759888, 
-3.47395133972168, -3.70814967155457, -3.25252461433411, -3.42652940750122, 
-3.37687730789185, -3.57012510299683, -3.79865074157715, -3.56782031059265, 
-3.55748176574707, -3.79533123970032, -3.51380968093872, -3.8156909942627, 
-3.61043334007263, -3.84270167350769, -3.67433190345764, -3.81427645683289, 
-3.80643391609192, -3.56018972396851, -3.83699107170105, -3.62709188461304, 
-3.75777626037598, -3.84473013877869, -3.64597678184509, -3.51665759086609, 
-3.70861983299255, -3.61876273155212, -3.72858834266663, -4.06253290176392, 
-3.97517681121826, -3.77920961380005, -3.25707650184631, -3.53454208374023, 
-3.14036655426025, -3.76010417938232, -3.53100967407227, -3.79575705528259, 
-3.77562570571899, -3.71199631690979, -3.63523483276367, -3.55303573608398, 
-3.73708510398865, -3.8654191493988, -3.75371766090393, -3.39529395103455, 
-3.5087423324585, -3.76858234405518, -3.27294230461121, -3.51291465759277, 
-3.5897159576416, -3.59522104263306, -3.72381043434143, -3.65958666801453, 
-4.01140213012695, -3.89993095397949, -3.80350923538208, -3.79413294792175, 
-4.02849149703979, -3.79621315002441, -3.09956812858582, -3.81814932823181, 
-3.73365259170532, -3.30368709564209, -3.42570853233337, -3.36531376838684, 
-3.57714676856995, -3.99519300460815, -3.8405442237854, -3.80736303329468, 
-4.11514949798584, -3.8206262588501, -3.81878995895386, -3.39630246162415, 
-3.81526851654053, -3.34133982658386, -3.47912859916687, -3.75328516960144, 
-3.06075572967529, -3.58890318870544, -3.70843410491943, -3.34376883506775, 
-3.84624218940735, -3.5749146938324, -4.03315925598145, -3.66028523445129, 
-3.2373788356781, 
-3.93130111694336, -4.11096096038818, -3.84883522987366, -3.90472340583801, 
-3.86706209182739, -4.03439426422119, -4.12989568710327, -4.01405668258667, 
-3.99284100532532, -3.86394143104553, -3.92312788963318,
```

Comment: Use `dput(yourdata)` and paste the results into your question instead. A printout is difficult to import into R.

Comment: `new_vec <- vec - mean(vec) + 100`

Comment: @dcarlson Edited

Answer (score 1):

First create z-scores (mean=0, sd=1):

```
z <- scale(x)
```

Then convert to mean=100, sd=100

```
xmod <- z * 100 + 100
mean(xmod)
# [1] 100
sd(xmod)
# [1] 100
summary(xmod)
#        V1        
#  Min.   :-99.46  
#  1st Qu.: 32.31  
#  Median : 83.33  
#  Mean   :100.00  
#  3rd Qu.:150.84  
#  Max.   :630.09
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a normal distribution.

```
# your data
head(vec)
[1] -3.630924 -3.465714 -3.239579 -3.089863 -3.842719 -3.636238

mean(rnorm( 1000, 100-(mean(vec)), 5) + vec)
[1] 100.0151
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_vec = (vec - mean(vec) * 100 + 100)
```